# Append variable to shell script like URL variables?

Tags: bash

I'm using Carbon Copy Cloner to backup some files and run a shell script after the backup process has completed.

*Note: You can save a scheduled backup in Carbon Copy Cloner and set it to run a specific shell script after the backup.*

The shell script emailbackupstatus.sh looks like this and works fine:

```
#!/bin/sh

(sleep 10; /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print" /Library/Logs/CCC.stats | tail -n 9 | mail -s "Backup completed" myname@mydomain.com) &
```

*Note: The plist file CCC.stats unfortunately does not contain the name of my saved backup schedule.*

But as I have several scheduled backups running every day, I get several identical emails every day. Therefore I would like to append a variable to the shell script, so that I can change the email subject to something like this:
"Backup of $backupName completed"

**Pass variable to shell script:**
Is it possible to somehow pass a variable to my shell script, like you can do with the GET url variables in PHP? Something like this: `emailbackupstatus.sh&$backupName="Just testing"`

**Or even better:**
Just get the name of my saved sheduled backup in Carbon Copy Cloner and append it to the email subject?

**The email I get looks like this:**
   Dict {
       targetDisk = root@backup.myserver.net:/Volumes/BACKUPDESTINATION/
       date = Sun Dec 28 00:24:52 CET 2010
       dataCopied = 0
       elapsedTime = 1467.495361
       sourceDisk = /Volumes/BACKUPSOURCE
       exitStatus = 0
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to your shell script as you would to any other program:

```
$ some_script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash2.html) is a small tutorial as to how to use them in your script.

Answer (score 0):

`$ ./script.sh foo bar mysubject`

can be accessed by example as positional (numbered) variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello arg1=$1 and arg2=$2"

echo "here I am" |mail -s "My submject is $3" me@domain.com
```